# copy data from one table into another based on certain criteria

Tags: excel-formula

so i have pulled information from an webpages api into a table but i need to copy the results into a seperate table based on results

explaining best i can here but its 3am and brains gone smooth.

if that makes sense

```
table 1 https://prnt.sc/3b9UqXeJU2-A
table 2 https://prnt.sc/4N3ap1wh2K6g
table 3 https://prnt.sc/kKFqPfDYWBke
```

so i want to copy the wins and losses (amounts) from table 1 based on the data in table 2 into the respective columns on table 3

any times on how to go about this? is it best to use vba or is there a excel formula im missing

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see how this question relates to VB.NET specifically or possibly even at all, so I have removed the tag. If it does relate to VB.NET, you need to explain exactly how in the question.

Comment: You also need to provide a much better explanation of the problem. If those poorly formatted URLs are supposed to be links to relevant information, you need to include that information directly in the question. No critical information should be accessible only via a link, which could be broken in future.

Comment: ok i will redo the question the best i can.